# why high order component is not working in react?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-redux, react-dom

could you please tell me why this  high order component not working .I am trying to show button and label using `HOC` .Here is my code

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ygpVeZ

```
var D = (comp) => class extends React.Component{
  render (){
    return (<comp/>)
  }
}

class A extends React.Component {
  render(){
    return (
      <button>hrllo</button>
    )
  }
}
class B extends React.Component {
  render(){
    return (
      <label> hello</label>
    )
  }
}

const PP =D(B)
const PPP =D(A)

class C extends React.Component {
  render(){
    return (
      <div>
         <PP></PP>
          <PPP></PPP>
      </div>

    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<C/>,document.getElementById('root'))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

React components must start with a capital letter as you can read in the [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#specifying-the-react-element-type).

> Capitalized types indicate that the JSX tag is referring to a React
>   component. These tags get compiled into a direct reference to the
>   named variable, so if you use the JSX  expression, Foo must be
>   in scope.

```
var D = (comp) => class extends React.Component{
  render (){
    return (<comp/>)
  }
}
```

should be

```
var D = (Comp) => class extends React.Component{
  render (){
    return (<Comp/>)
  }
}
```

[codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JEMbmE)

Comment: thanks for answer ..could you please tell me how to show `count` state value in child componenet http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ygpVeZ